# Is there a free unilimited API to get the top 100 billboard with Youtube music videos?

Tags: youtube-api

On http://www.youtube.com/music, there's a Billboard hot 100 list. Is there a API to get this list programmatically?

I know there's a youtube API to get the top music videos: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular_Music?v=2&max-results=50&time=this_week, however it only returns 50 videos and the list is not the Billboard chart.

And there's also a rss for Billboard top 100, http://www.billboard.com/rss/charts/hot-100, but it doesn't return Youtube video links and thumbnail images.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result using pagination.
There is an example from Jeffrey Posnick of how to do it:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/4sjeUOy9ojE

```
int count = 1; 
    boolean moreResults = true; 
    while (moreResults) { 
      for (VideoEntry videoEntry : videoFeed.getEntries()) { 
        // Do whatever you'd like with videoEntry... 
        System.out.println(videoEntry.getMediaGroup().getVideoId()); 
      } 
      if (count++ >= 10) { 
        moreResults = false; 
      } else { 
        Link nextLink = videoFeed.getNextLink(); 
        if (nextLink == null) { 
          moreResults = false; 
        } else { 
          videoFeed = service.query(new YouTubeQuery(new 
URL(nextLink.getHref())), VideoFeed.class); 
        } 
      } 
    }
```